# SharePoint Javascript Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, master-pages

I am having a weird problem. I created some custom javascript and referenced it in my master page for one of my sites in SharePoint.  For some reason the javascript works totally fine when I am logged in with my admin account, however, when logged in with my regular user account the javascript does not seem to work.  Has anyone ever experienced an issue like this? If so could you please point me in the direction of how to solve this problem. My javascript hides a link when the page is ready and depending on the current user logged in, displays the link if the user is in a specific group.  Below is my code...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#rating-link').hide();
        checkGroupMembership();
    });

    function checkGroupMembership() {
         $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
            userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
            async: false,
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                if ($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='Test']").length == 1) {
                    $('#rating-link').show();              
                }
            }
        });         
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Are you able to make that SPServices call as a non-privileged user?

Comment: Mmmm I am not sure, that may very well be the problem.  How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You should just be able to open up developer console and attempt to make that call. It will probably give you an error response in your completion function, though verify that by looking at the API docs. I haven't touched SP in a couple years

Comment: Thanks, will do. Fingers crossed.

Comment: No go... Also, even in the document.ready function when I throw an alert it does not show up under my regular account, only my admin account

Comment: Hot Damn!!! Figured out the problem.  Apparently I needed to check in the  .js files that reference SPServices as well as add jQuery to my site assets rather than referencing it via google hosted libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Hot Damn!!! Figured out the problem. Apparently I needed to check in the .js files that reference SPServices as well as add jQuery to my site assets rather than referencing it via google hosted libraries.